# Finding an n players from 55 chess games

Tags: combinatorics

> In chess tournament each player, from all $n$ players, played one game with every another player. All together there was $55$ games played. How many players took part of the tournament?

I know the answer is $11$, but how to show the calculation?

I came up with $11$ from random testing of combinatorics $C(k,n) = C(2,11)= \dfrac{11!}{2!(11-2)!}=55$.

What would be the correct calculation to get count n of players from 55 chess games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From n players for game we choose two in $\binom{n}{2}$ ways there are 55 games so we need to solve equation
$$\binom{n}{2}=55$$
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=55$$
$$n(n-1)=110$$
$$n(n-1)=11\cdot(11-1)$$
$$n=11$$

Answer (score 4):

I believe the clearest way is to rigorously prove this from scratch (rather than "happening upon the correct answer through trial and error") is to go the other way, say "If there are $n$ players, how many games are played?" and get the answer $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Then solve $$55 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$noting that $n$ must be positive. This gives $n = 11$.